# ImageButton isn't the same size

Tags: android, android-button, android-image

I have problem with width of ImageButtons, it isn't the same size. I have experimented with all attributes for two hours and nothing. I create buttons at runtime and put inside row (also created at runtime). Does anybody know any solution for this ?
[image]

```
public static TableRow[] Create(List<Apartment> list){
        TableRow[] rows=null;
        try{
            rows=new TableRow[list.size()*3];
            int i=0;

            for(final Apartment ap : list){
                rows[3*i]=new TableRow(activity);
                rows[3*i+1]=new TableRow(activity);
                rows[3*i+2]=new TableRow(activity);

                rows[3*i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( 
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                rows[3*i+1].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( 
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                rows[3*i+2].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( 
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

                rows[3*i].setBackgroundColor(color_background[(i%2)]);
                rows[3*i+1].setBackgroundColor(color_background[(i%2)]);
                rows[3*i+2].setBackgroundColor(color_background[(i%2)]);

                TextView txtMainInform=new TextView(activity);
                txtMainInform.setText(ap.GetMainInformation());
                txtMainInform.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( 
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                rows[3*i].addView(txtMainInform);
                rows[3*i].setVisibility(1);

                TextView txtMoreInform=new TextView(activity);
                txtMoreInform.setText(ap.GetMoreInformation());
                txtMoreInform.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( 
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                rows[3*i+1].addView(txtMoreInform);

                ImageButton imbCall=new ImageButton(activity);
                imbCall.setImageResource(R.drawable.phone);
                imbCall.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                         if(ap.GetContact()!=null){
                          try {
                            activity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + ap.GetContact())));
                          } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                          }
                        }
                    }
                });
                imbCall.setMaxWidth(24);
                imbCall.setMinimumWidth(22);

                ImageButton imbGallery=new ImageButton(activity);
                imbGallery.setMaxWidth(24);
                imbGallery.setMinimumWidth(22);
                imbGallery.setImageResource(R.drawable.gallery_icon);


                ImageButton imbMap=new ImageButton(activity);
                imbMap.setImageResource(R.drawable.map);
                imbMap.setMaxWidth(24);  
                imbMap.setMinimumWidth(22);
                imbMap.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                           Intent i = new Intent(activity,ResultMap.class);
                           activity.startActivity(i);
                    }  
                });

                ImageButton imbWay=new ImageButton(activity);
                imbWay.setMaxWidth(24);
                imbWay.setMinimumWidth(22);
                imbWay.setImageResource(R.drawable.walker);

                rows[3*i+2].addView(imbCall);
                rows[3*i+2].addView(imbGallery);
                rows[3*i+2].addView(imbMap);
                rows[3*i+2].addView(imbWay);
                i++;
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
        return rows;
    }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the dimensions of the images you're putting in the buttons? And why are you setting the button dimensions as WRAP_CONTENT but then setting minimum and maximum widths rather than just setting the width to the height you want? Also, seriously consider defining this layout in XML -- it'll be a lot less verbose and more flexible, and you can automatically support different dimensions of screens by sizing your buttons in DIP rather than pixels.

Comment: Dimesions are 24x24px. I didn't put WRAP_CONTENT and FILL_PARENT for buttons, it is for rows where I put buttons.  I don't know how many rows I need to create, that is the reason why I cannot put in XML.

Comment: You can still use xml, just create an xml layout for the row.  Then you can inflate the row and add it as many times as you need.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you add each of those rows into the same TableLayout, or something to that effect? If so, it would associate the rows with another, so that the first item in one row is in the same column as the first item in another row.

I can barely tell by your image, but my guess would be that the extremely cut-off text at the top of the image is pushing the width of the column, widening the first button with it.

```
|longish text blagh |       |       |       |
|price              |       |       |       |
|blah               |       |       |       |
| [------BTN------] | [BTN] | [BTN] | [BTN] |
```

You could possibly fix it by putting the row of buttons into some other sort of view, if that happens to be the problem.